# localStorage json of 3 items

Tags: javascript, browser, local-storage

I want to have a *localStorage* entry that will be basically an array of 3 items. Of course, it will be set as JSON in the *localStorage*.

What's the best way of doing this? (an efficient way)

Like whenever I set a new item to that entry in the *localStorage*, and there are already 3 items, it will delete the first one and append the new one.

Can I do this somehow without getting the localStorage entry, then checking the item count in it, delete the first one if there are 3 and then append the new one and then save it. Is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: If there are already 3 elements, then you just `slice(1)` the existing array, and then append the new one.

Comment: I don't believe there is. You will need to get the item from localStorage, append to it (and remove the first if necessary), then set it again

Comment: @Rezaa91 thank you for your answer, I'll just do that then :) I just wanted to know if  I could to this without the whole thingy